# /tellraw with teleporting

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is there a way to use the "selector" command with tellraw so that it displays a players name in chat and THEN teleports that player to a location? I know how to do each separately but I don't know how to do both using the previously selected player who was chosen to be teleported. Please help.

Comment: It is in the chat or a command block?

Comment: Why would you not want to do it separately? If you want both to be instantly after each other, just use a redstone stream.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify Daniel's answer, you can assign a tag to a player when they click on a command in the chat using the following command in a tellraw command:

```
/scoreboard players tag @p add command_clicked
```

Then, in a repeating command block chain, you can execute the following 3 commands in order:

```
/say @a[tag=command_clicked]
/tp @a[tag=command_clicked] <destination>
/scoreboard players tag @a remove command_clicked
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to selector is like the example below:

```
/tellraw @a [{"selector":"@p","color":"dark_red"},{"text":" is now teleporting!","color":"red"}]
```

Then another one you could add if you want make execute `/execute` when they click:

```
/execute @a[tag=command_clicked] ~ ~ ~ /tellraw {command}
```

And another one doing:

```
/execute @a[tag=command_clicked] ~ ~ ~ /tp {command}
```

That might work, so like make tp a little bit more seconds tick like a redstone clock or maybe always active repeating and to make command blocks silent:

```
/gamerule commandBlockOutput false
```

It helps to make it silent to easily do a bunch; Deathrun is an example. You click something and teleport; that's one example.